# Why my commit-interval is not working?

Tags: spring-batch, commit, intervals

I have setted the commit interval of 1000 . But, it is not working. Still, i am getting items at random intervals to my item writer . please advise.

```
<batch:step id="step1" next ="step2">
            <batch:tasklet task-executor="simpleTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="20">          
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor"  writer="itemWriter"  commit-interval="1000" />
                 <batch:listeners>  
                    <batch:listener ref="appJobExecutionListener" />
                        <batch:listener ref="appJobFailureLoggerListener" />    
                    <batch:listener ref="customStepListener" />             
                    </batch:listeners> 
            </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by random intervals in your item writer. How did you determine that you are getting random intervals in your item writer?

Comment: Since , i setted 1000 as my commit interval, i was expecting once item count reached 1000 it should reach item writer .But it was not happening. for e.g. i have file of 10 records. i expect 10 records to come to item writer at one shot .but it is coming as 1 , 2, 5 and  2 .  hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an Async executor. (Guessing, you have not shown in the config) The async executor is set to 20, which means you can have up to 20 threads executing in parallel.

If you want to read records up to the commit interval and then process one chunk at a time, you should drop the task-executor from the config